# Pseudocode for brute-force algorithm to find largest product of two numbers in a list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to come up with a pseudocode brute-force algorithm that finds the largest product of two numbers in a list a[sub1] to a[subn], with n greater than or equal to 2. Right now, I have

```
for ( i = 1 to n -1)

    a[subi] = a[subi-1] * a[subi+1]

    for (j = a[sub j+1] to n)

        a[sub j] = a[sub j-1] * a[sub j+1]

    end for

end for

return `a[sub i]`

return `a[sub j]`
```

However, this is not correct. I feel like there's something simple I'm missing here, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just multiply together the two largest values in the list?

Comment: I still cannot figure what are you trying to do after reading your code, isn't it just 2 for loops and test which combination of a[i]*a[j] is the greatest?

Comment: You could do a linear run through of the list and pick out the two highest values, and multiply them together to get your result.

Comment: This might be a little better stated. How's this? @shole @IsaacTurner                                         `large = a_1 * a_2
for(i = 1 to n)
    for(j = i+1 to n)
        if(large < a_i * a_j)
            large = a_i * a_j`

Comment: I think @NickZuber 's solution is the best as it is linear: find largest 2 negative number & largest 2 positive number, take the greater product

Comment: You can use randomized select algorithm to get the largest two numbers. It will be a linear time solution.

Comment: The product of the two largest, or the two smallest numbers might be the largest product. It's probably a good idea to check both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
largest_product = a[1] * a[2]

for ( i = 1 to n -1)
    for (j = i + 1 to n)
        product = a [i] * a [j]

        if (product > largest_product)
            largest_product = product
        end if
    end for

end for

return largest_product
```

**Edit**:

The comments to your question suggest a more efficient solution in linear time.

Implementation will follow up.

Comment: The second implementation needs to shuffle rejected largest candidates from the first to the second buffer. It also fails for negative numbers.

Comment: Sailu: The 2nd largest won't pick up values previously 1st largest from earlier iterations, or newer duplicates for that matter. Consider the sequence { 1, 0, 2 } yielding 0 as the second largest. As for negative numbers consider the sequence { +1, +2, -3, -4 } where the (+1)*(+2)=2 is found in place of (-3)*(-4)=12.